# UITableViewCell addSubview Repeating Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Pretty simple issue. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I need to add a custom `UILabel`. So I try this in the given method:

```
UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//Other properties etc

if (indexPath.row == 0) titleLbl.text = @"1";
else if (indexPath.row == 1) titleLbl.text = @"2";

[cell addSubview:titleLbl];
```

Issue is that when scrolling down my table, the label starts repeating and duplicating.

How can I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add that label as a subview in the

```
if (!cell) {
  cell =...;
  UILabel *label;
  label.tag = 1;
  [cell addSubview:label];
}

UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
if (indexPath.row == 0) label.text = @"1";
```

This way it will only be added when the cell is being allocated. To retrieve that label give it a tag and use viewWithTag method of your cell

Comment: Worked like magic and allows me to add the subview without using a subclass of UITableViewCell, great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your cell is being reused and every time your are adding the label.

Better would be to subclass UITableViewCell in which you add the UILabel. Do not forget to override the prepareForReuse method where you would set the text of the label to nil