# UITableView reloadData() overwrites previous cell data

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata, reuseidentifier

I'm dynamically creating a UITableView and populating it with an Array, which is populated my a Dictionary. Issue is that when I make some changes in Dictionary, re-populate the Array accordingly and reload tableview data, previous cell datas remain and new data is written over the previous ones. I tried lots of workarounds, like changing the order of method calls, using viewWithTag on subviews, removing subviews from superviews before adding again etc. None worked, since most of the answers were old and had to do with "(cell == nil)" issue whereas I'm not taking that path. Here is the code:

```
var sepetDict: [String: Int] = [:]

var sepetDictCopy = [String]()

override fun viewDidLoad() {
    sepetTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sepetDialogView.bounds.size.width, sepetDialogView.bounds.size.height)
    sepetTableView.delegate = self
    sepetTableView.dataSource = self
    sepetTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "sepetCell")
}

func sepetClick() {
    sepetDictCopy.removeAll()
    sepetDictCopy = Array(sepetDict.keys)
    sepetTableView.reloadData()
    sepetTableView.removeFromSuperview()

    self.view.addSubview(sepetDialogView)
    sepetDialogView.addSubview(sepetTableView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sepetCell = sepetTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sepetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let sepetNameLabel = UILabel()

    sepetNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sepetDialogView.bounds.size.width / 2, 60)
    sepetNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(25 + sepetDialogView.bounds.size.width / 4 , 30)
    sepetNameLabel.font = sepetNameLabel.font.fontWithSize(13)
    sepetNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    sepetNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    sepetNameLabel.text = sepetDictCopy[indexPath.row]

    sepetCell.contentView.addSubview(sepetNameLabel)

    return sepetCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sepetDictCopy.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

In this case, I click on a UIButton, it pops up a UIView and UITableView is added to this UIView as a subView. At first click, everything works great. When I close that UIView and re-click on the button, this time tableview loads with new data (correct data as well) but it overwrites the previous data. In the provided code, I know I don't add any data to the array, but issue is the same since for example I had "Pizza" written in UILabel and when I reloaded the table, there still was "Pizza", but this time darker (which tells me that label is overwritten on previous label). Say I add "Burger" to the array, tableview shows "Burger" and "Pizza", but this time "Burger" is written over the previous "Pizza" at index 0 and "Pizza" is at index 1 alone. I can also provide additional information or some pictures of the issue if not understood correctly.

Comment: Have you tried adding the label to the cell in the storyboard and then linking it to a custom class or grabbing it using `viewWithTag` (I know you mentioned using this method but I don't have a context as to how you are using it). Maybe you should be setting the tag on the `sepetNameLabel` and attempting to retrieve it before creating and adding a new label. Basically with the code above you are ALWAYS adding another label even if the cell already has one. You need to check if it has one (likely view the `tag` property and then checking for `viewWithTag` before adding the initial label)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell addSubview Repeating Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702635/uitableviewcell-addsubview-repeating-object)

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't quite understand the concept of viewWithTag method. I rearranged my code and it worked. For those who are looking for an up to date answer and code, here it is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var sepetCell: UITableViewCell! = sepetTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("")

    if (sepetCell == nil) {
        sepetCell = sepetTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sepetCell")!

        let sepetNameLabel = UILabel()

        sepetNameLabel.tag = 1

        sepetNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sepetDialogView.bounds.size.width / 2, 60)
        sepetNameLabel.center = CGPointMake(25 + sepetDialogView.bounds.size.width / 4 , 30)
        sepetNameLabel.font = sepetNameLabel.font.fontWithSize(13)
        sepetNameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        sepetNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

        sepetCell.contentView.addSubview(sepetNameLabel)
    }

    let sepetNameLabel = sepetCell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    sepetNameLabel.text = sepetDictCopy[indexPath.row]

    return sepetCell
}
```

Comment: Why do you add the view in code? It's much easier to use a custom table view cell designed with IBOutlets in Interface Builder. Look at the date of the tutorials you're using. Many of them suggest old-fashioned procedures like `viewWithTag` in this case.

Comment: I'm working with different screen sizes and all of them needs to be precisely sized. I couldn't get the same performance using storyboard for that purpose.

Comment: A u t o l a y o u t ;-)

Comment: I find it easier to programmatically create views. I'm new to Swift, so maybe I get used to auto layout in future :)